# ArgumentException when adding many coordinates on the map

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8, location

I would like to add some pushpins that can be clickable on the map. First, I would like to display them but when I add them on a map, an ArgumentException is occured and my application crashes.
If I add only one place on the map, it works but when I'm trying to add more places, it crashes. The whole list has been traversed.

My code:

```
var myCircle = new Ellipse
                {
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                    Height = 20,
                    Width = 20,
                    Opacity = 50
                };
MapLayer locationLayer = new MapLayer();
foreach (var place in r.Result)
                {
                    //It's a method that I created to get the placecoordinate in good format because it can be with commas
                    var placeCoordinate = Geolocalisation.GetCoordinateInGoodFormat(place.Google_lat,
                                                                                    place.Google_lng);
                    if (placeCoordinate == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var locationOverlay = new MapOverlay
                        {
                            Content = myCircle,
                            PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
                            GeoCoordinate = placeCoordinate
                        };

                    Debug.WriteLine(place.Title + ", lat: " + place.Google_lat + ", long: " + place.Google_lng);
                    //Display e.g.: soleil du midi, lat: 50.8382836, long: 4.3975321

                    locationLayer.Add(locationOverlay);

}
mapControl.Layers.Add(locationLayer); //my map in XAML
```

The error :

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried creating a new instance of the circle for every point on the map because you can't add the same UIElement (in this case the Circle) to the visual tree twice.

```
      var locationOverlay = new MapOverlay
            {
                    Content = new Ellipse()
                            {
                                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                                    Height = 20,
                                    Width = 20,
                                    Opacity = 50
                            },
                    PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
                    GeoCoordinate = placeCoordinate
            };
```